# SQL join using substring in snowflake

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run this query but it's taking too long because to join with my calling_zones table and also creating multiple records. for e.g if my terminating number is '9974552425' then i will get output with 4 duplicate records matching with calling zones '99','997','9974',''99745'.

Output required: I would like to only get the only match where my max length of terminating number matches with calling zone area code and replace this join ("ON") statement accordingly. because my query is taking maximum amount of time running this join. maybe if regex_substring  or something can fast the query performance.

I would appreciate any help to resolve this problem.

```
SELECT
    a.gsmcallreferencenumber
    , a.CONNECT_DATETIME
    , a.TOTAL_CALL_DURATION_SEC
    , a.ORIGINATING_NUMBER
    , a.TERMINATING_NUMBER
    , cz.ZONE_AREA_CODE_PRICE
    , cz.ZONE_AREA_CODE_PRICE_CURRENCY
    , cz.ZONE_AREA_CODE
    , cz.ZONE_DESTINATION
    , ROUND(nvl(1.0 * (a.TOTAL_CALL_DURATION_SEC / 60) * cz.ZONE_AREA_CODE_PRICE, 0), 2) AS CALL_COST
FROM
    tablex  a
    LEFT JOIN CALLING_ZONES cz
        ON SUBSTR(A.TERMINATING_NUMBER, 1,length(cz.ZONE_AREA_CODE) ) = cz.ZONE_AREA_CODE
GROUP BY
    a.CONNECT_DATETIME
    , a.TOTAL_CALL_DURATION_SEC
    , a.ORIGINATING_NUMBER
    , a.TERMINATING_NUMBER
    , cz.ZONE_AREA_CODE_PRICE
    , cz.ZONE_AREA_CODE_PRICE_CURRENCY
    , cz.ZONE_AREA_CODE
    , cz.ZONE_DESTINATION;
```

sample data

```
Table a                       Table Calling Zone
a.Terminating number             zone_area_code 

9974552425                         5324
99526552425                        995
5324664892                         9952
3274639201                         99526
6473294465                         997 
                                   9974
```

current output with query mentioned

Output

```
Terminating_Number      Zone area code
9974552425                997
9974552425                9974
99526552425               995
99526552425               9952
99526552425               99526
5324664892                 5324
3274639201                 null
6473294465                 null
```

Desired Output:

```
9974552425                9974
99526552425               99526
5324664892                 5324
3274639201                 null
6473294465                 null
```

Comment: 1. please tag your sql engine , 2. please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic.

Comment: I am unable to provide sample data since I am working with confidential data. But i can make this question simple by saying i have table a and table b. and i would like to perform  join by using substring of table a and match that with table b column id. and i need a result where my max length of table a substring matches with table b column id.

Comment: For the purposes of this question, instead of focusing in the whole process - is it ok if we only focus on the second part? Meaning, once you have all the duplicates, would you like us to find a way to find the best match within those presented?

Comment: I would say, I am more focusing on making this "join on" statement a way so that it will just return one value for one data because my table a is over 5M records and calling zone is over 15K records so currently it is performing cross join with calling zone table. Hence, it is generating 5M*15K records. Hope that make sense

Comment: @felipe hoffa, i can try if you have any thoughts for second part, meaning how to get keep the best matched zone area code and remove the duplicate row without using windows function and partitioning by  a.CONNECT_DATETIME, a.ORIGINATING_NUMBER, a.TERMINATING_NUMBER, these three columns? I am asking without using windows function because i already tried and it's not helping.